# I don't understand how to use the unicode for emojis in discord bot

Tags: unicode, discord, discord.py, emoji

Specifically, I do not understand how to use the unicode for emoji `Keycap digit one` in building a discord bot. I found for example `\U0001F44D` for `thumbs up` and `\U0001F44F` for `clap hands` but I just don't know how to use `keycap digit one`.

I found sources saying codepoint for `digit one` is `U+31`, `U+FE0F`. But I just do not understand how to use them. Links are as follows:

1. https://emojipedia.org/emoji/1/
2. https://www.emojiall.com/en/emoji/1

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the C / C++ / Java Source Code of that emoji to use it as a string in Python. You can use this little piece of beautiful code to get the emojis you want:

```py
@client.command()
async def toUnicode(ctx, emoji):
    await ctx.send(f'{emoji} **{json.dumps(emoji)[1:-1]}**')
```

**Note:** Remember to import `json`

---

[image]

So, the C / C++ / Java Source Code for 1️⃣ would be **1\ufe0f\u20e3**